# How to handle org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring mvc app in which I am using Trip model and TripStop model. Trip model has list of trip stop models. Following is my Trip model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Trip")
public class TripModel {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "tripid")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int tripId;

    @Column(name = "tripname")
    private String tripName;

    @Column(name = "tripdesc")
    private String tripDesc;

    @Column(name = "createdate")
    private Date createDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tripModel", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<TripStopModel> tripStopList;
}
```

Following is my trip stop model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TripStop")
public class TripStopModel {
    @Id
    @Column(name="tripstopid")
    @GeneratedValue 
    private int tripStopId; 

    @Column(name="datetime")
    private String tripStopDateTime;

    @Column(name="createts")
    private Date tripStopCreateTime;

    @ManyToOne(optional=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="locationid")
    private LocationModel locationModel;

    public LocationModel getLocationModel() {
        return locationModel;
    }

    public void setLocationModel(LocationModel locationModel) {
        this.locationModel = locationModel;
    }
    @ManyToOne(optional=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="userid")
    private UserModel userModel;

    @ManyToOne(optional=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="tripid")
    private TripModel tripModel;
}
```

This works fine. But when trip id is 0 in TripStop table, it shows following exception:

```
02:32:43,784 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.example.scm.model.TripModel#0]
```

Is there any option with which we can used trip id = 0 in TripStop table, without any exception? How can I allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tripID is defaulting to 0 because you are using primitives. Switch to primitive wrappers so these values can default to null and this should solve it

Comment: Thanks for answer. You mean Integer in place of int ?

Comment: yes - this will default tripID to null instead of 0, and solve your problem

Comment: And in database, tripid field should be numeric ? But it says, null cannot be assigned to numeric.

Comment: I was trying to address why you are setting the value to 0. Do you intend TripStop to always link to Trip? If so then you will need to set the value of trip in TripStop. Another option is to allow tripid in TripStop to have null values. It depends on your app/model